# Deploy VSTO Excel 2010 AddIn automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-2010, excel-interop

Is there a way to deploy a vsto Excel 2010 AddIn to a list of machines automatically? One thing I had considered was adding a reference to the .vsto file in a user startup script. Any other ideas though? Has anyone performed this sort of deployment before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a silent installer, and then copy and run from any batch script, it can be startup

Comment: Silent installer is a good idea, make sure your users have admin rights to install this. If you installing as different user make sure the addins registry entries are at Machinelevel rather than CurrentUser level.